# Conditional colorscheme in .vimrc

Tags: vim

I am using vim and MacVim. I have a 256-colour colorscheme which I like for my MacVim, but if I load it into regular vim, it obviously does not work (I get blinkies instead). I would like to be able to use the same vim config on all my systems, so:

Is there a way to check for palette size in `.vimrc` and set one of the two colorschemes accordingly? If that is not feasible, then checking for MacVim vs. vim would also be okay.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You've got several options.

I think your best bet is to load one colorscheme in `.vimrc`, and another in `.gvimrc` (or in your case, just don't load a colorscheme in `.vimrc` at all). The `.gvimrc` colorscheme will only be loaded when you're running the GUI version of MacVim.

If you don't want to split your configuration across multiple files, you can also use a conditional like this one in `.vimrc`:

```
if has('gui_running')
    colorscheme mycrazycolors
endif
```

Finally, if you really do want to know the number of colors available, you can check the `t_Co` setting:

```
:echo &t_Co
```

`t_Co` is empty in the GUI version of MacVim, so you'll probably still want to use a variation of the `has()` technique. In fact, the default `.vimrc` does something similar to determine when to enable syntax highlighting:

```
if &t_Co > 2 || has("gui_running")
    syntax on
endif
```

For the sake of completeness, I should mention that you could also expand your colorscheme file to include reasonable settings for color terminals. This is a fair amount of work, however, and it might be easier to just switch to a terminal application that supports more colors.

See these topics for more info:

```
:help has()
:help termcap
:help termcap-colors
```

Comment: Thanks for these, particularly for `.gvimrc` - I didn't know that one existed.

Answer (score 5):

I recently did something like this to use the same .vimrc on all our Linux systems, but use the Ubuntu monospace font if I was running on Ubuntu:

```
if (match(system("cat /etc/issue"), "Ubuntu") != -1)
    set guifont=Ubuntu\ Mono\ 13
else
    set guifont=Monospace\ 11
endif
```

It seems to me that you could do something similar to detect if you are running on a Mac or otherwise:

```
if (match(system("uname -s"), "Darwin") != -1)
    colorscheme macscheme
else
    colorscheme otherscheme
endif
```

Note that I used http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uname to find out what uname reports on OS X. I don't have a Mac here handy to try it on but I imagine that's accurate.

Comment: FYI: `uname -s` print out `Darwin` on my mac.